# Compiled Windows Forms project won't run on Windows 2008 Server machine

Tags: c#, winforms, windows-server-2008-x64

I've a very simple C# windows forms project. It works great on my development PC (Win7 x64) but after compile won't run on Windows 2008 x64.

Any ideas why?

Thakns.

EDIT (more info):

The error I get on the server is this:

```
Description:
  Stopped working

Problem signature:
  Problem Event Name:   CLR20r3
  Problem Signature 01: servertester.exe
  Problem Signature 02: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 03: 4dbd6fe8
  Problem Signature 04: ServerTester
  Problem Signature 05: 1.0.0.0
  Problem Signature 06: 4dbd6fe8
  Problem Signature 07: 3
  Problem Signature 08: 15
  Problem Signature 09: System.IO.FileNotFoundException
  OS Version:   6.0.6002.2.2.0.272.7
  Locale ID:    1037
```

the platform target of the project is Any PC, though being compiled on x64.
The target framework is .Net 4 client profile.

Hope it helps :)

Comment: what's the error? come on, help us out here.

Comment: You are right! sorry :) in a min.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a file-not-found exception, could be as simple as forgetting to copy a file or not specifying the full path name.  Don't guess at this, implement a handler for the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException event and log or display the value of e.ExceptionObject.ToString().  It tells you where your code bombed.

Comment: Yep. missed a file... which was supposed to be added automatically :) thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Random guess given that your question has absolutely no detail whatsoever. Did you remember to install the corresponding .NET framework on the server?

Comment: Sure :) What details are missing? I'd be glad to add them

Comment: Come on man, you're a developer. How useful do you think "it won't run" is as an aid to diagnosis? What sort of detail would you want if you were in my position?

Comment: well, it states "file not found". do you reference any external files? something you didn't copy or doesn't exist on the server machine?

Comment: Nothing I know of. Maybe some referenced file? How can I make sure that all files are present on the target machine?